# Split a single string into several portions when decoding a JSON (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, string, codable, jsondecoder

I have a JSON file containing around 3000 unique id codes of the following format (10 digits):

```
1012111000
```

I am currently importing it into a simple struct of the following format:

```
struct Codes: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: String
}
```

using the following extension:

```
extension Bundle {
  func decode<T: Codable>( file: String) -> T {
    guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
      fatalError("Failred to locate \(file) in bundle")
    }
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
      fatalError("Failred to load \(file) from bundle")
    }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
      fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle")
    }
    return loaded
  }
}
```

and call

```
let code: [Codes] = Bundle.main.decode(file: "codes.json")
```

This works as expected and the data is available in Swift.
But.
The id code is actually made up of 4 individual codes.  The first 3 characters are one 3-digit code, the 4th character is another single-digit code, the 5th and 6th characters form a third 2-digit code and the last four characters form a final 4-digit code.  As such I'd like to instead import into a struct as follows:  Note in this that id4 is unique but id1, id2 and id3 will have duplicates.

```
struct Codes: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id1: String    // 1st-3rd character (3 digits)
  let id2: String    // 4th character (1 digit)
  let id3: String    // 5th-6th character (2 digits)
  let id4: String    // 7th-10th characters (4 digits)
}
```

Any advice on how to achieve this in a nice neat way would be appreciated.  I know there are numerous ways of parsing strings but I'm not sure how best to acomplish this within a loop.  I should also note that the decoder is generic due to it needing to import a number of other (simpler) JSONs and this functionality needs to remain.

best,
Sy

Comment: Quick code suggestion: make `id` private, `id1`, `id2`, `id3` & `id4` lazy, and then are created from `id`. Since your code already works (I assume), it should be the fatest way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make "Codes" compatible with what you already have and have the component ids,
try this approach, or something similar:

```
struct Codes: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    
    func id1() -> String { string(from: 0, to: 3) }
    func id2() -> String { string(from: 3, to: 4) }
    func id3() -> String { string(from: 5, to: 7) }
    func id4() -> String { string(from: 6, to: 10) }

   // or using lazy var
   // lazy var id1: String = { string(from: 0, to: 3) }()
   // lazy var id2: String = { string(from: 3, to: 4) }()
   // lazy var id3: String = { string(from: 5, to: 7) }()
   // lazy var id4: String = { string(from: 6, to: 10) }()
    
    private func string(from: Int, to: Int) -> String {
        let start = id.index(id.startIndex, offsetBy: from)
        let end = id.index(id.startIndex, offsetBy: to)
        return String(id[start..<end])
    }
}
```

Note, when using lazy var you need to declare:

```
var code = Codes(id: "1012111000")
```

not

```
let code = Codes(id: "1012111000")
```

as with the functions.

Comment: This unnecessarily offsets all indices from the startIndex. Change `to` to `length` and offset the length from the already known start or simply subtract `from` and offset the result

Comment: Wouldn't `lazy var` be a better choice? They wouldn't be calculated again each time? And minor, but would avoid the `()` when calling them?

Comment: fair enough comment, I'll put the option with lazy var.

Comment: Hello - I tried the `lazy var` approach instead of `func`.  I also replaced the initial decoder call with a `var codes: [Codes]` rather than `let` but this doesn't work for me - it errors with "Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'codes' is a 'let' constant

Comment: I've also had some issues with lazy var, maybe someone can show us how to set them up and use them cleanly in SwiftUI. Until then, use the functions.